# Cannot get ion-back-button to work properly

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

The ion-back-button I am trying to use on this page refuses to appear. There is nothing in the start slot when I should get a " < Back " button appearing.

selected_card.page.html

```
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot='start'>
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{restaurant.name}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

selected_card.page.ts

```
import { ModalController, NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RestaurantsService } from '../services/restaurants.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-selected-card',
  templateUrl: './selected-card.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selected-card.page.scss'],
})
export class SelectedCardPage implements OnInit {
  // value: string;
  restaurant: any;
  constructor(private restaurantsService: RestaurantsService,
              private modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private navParams: NavParams) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.restaurant = this.navParams.get('restaurant');
    console.log(this.restaurant);
  }
  selectRestaurant() {
    console.log(this.customRestaurant)
    this.customRestaurant()
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }

}
```

Let me know if y'all have questions! Really cannot figure out why this will not work when it works every other time I use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your question though if you wanted **ion-back-button** you are not using this component inside your **ion-buttons**. **ion-back-button** should be used instead of **ion-button** ...

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot='start'>
       <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{restaurant.name}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: I was messing around with my code and took out the ion-back-button trying to get it to work.

Comment: try to use  <ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>

Answer (score 0):

This should work for showing back button.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
       <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title>
     Room info page
  </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```